# HTML/CSS webpage structure

Tags: html, css

Got a small issue with this website structure: www.bigideaadv.com/xsp

Looking to have this container fill the middle of the screen between the top and bottom navigation. I'd also like to have the middle collapse with the resizing of the window with a scrollbar. Can't seem to make it work quite right. Anyone have any thoughts?

```
    <div id="top_navigation">   
        <div id="navigation_inside">
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href="">Schedule Demo</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sales</a></li>
                <li><p style="float:left; margin:0;">Search</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<form style="margin:0 0 0 5px; padding:0; float:left;"><input class="search" type="text" /><input type="hidden"></form></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="navigation2">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="">People</a></li>
                <li><a href="">News + Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="scroller">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom_navigation">
        <div id="twitter_bar">
            <div id="twitter">
                <h5><img src="images/twitter_bird.png" width="23" height="16" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>@XSPGlobal:</b>&nbsp;</h5>
                <p>Loading...</p>
                <noscript><h5>This feature requires JavaScript</h5></noscript>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="blog_posts">
            <p>Here is where the blog posts will go.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom_navigation_inside">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Partners</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Interfaces</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="">XACT Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Milestones</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Awards + Recognition</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Client Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Press Releases</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Social Responsibility</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="social_links">
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="23" height="24" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="23" height="24" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com"><img src="images/linkedin.png" width="23" height="24" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #container {
        margin: 72px 0 72px 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #top_navigation {
        position: fixed;
        min-width: 1010px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 72px;
        background: url('../images/opaque.png') repeat;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    #bottom_navigation {
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 1010px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 172px;
        background: url('../images/opaque.png') repeat;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

Comment: You've tagged the question with jquery but I see no mention or usage of jquery.  Is the implication that you are open to using jquery as a solution?

Comment: I have supersized.js which is a jquery background resizing script. Sven's solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the container to position fixed with a top of 72px and a bottom of 172px.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks. This'll solve a lot of my issues.